# MySQL Difficult Question on auto_increment

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I can't seem to figure out a MYSQL command or set of commands that will allow me to create an 'id' field, add auto_increment values, and then set it as the primary key.

The reason I want to do this is that I have an existing table with millions of rows and I want to assign a unique ID to each row which would become the primary key and have it auto_increment.

Is there a way to do this with SQL syntax or do I need to write a script?

Comment: Need more info. What does your schema look like currently? Does the table in question already have a primary key, auto_increment column, or clustered index?

Comment: It has no primary key, no auto_increment column, and no indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just figured it out in case anyone else needs this in the future:

```
alter table test add column id int(9) unsigned auto_increment PRIMARY KEY;
```

Answer (score 3):

This should be relatively simple:

```
ALTER TABLE `myTable` ADD `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can create a new table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY (id), KEY(b))
ENGINE=InnoDB SELECT b,c FROM original;
```

Comment: Any way to do it on the existing table so all the data doesn't need to be copied from one table to another?